# Is there a way to ignore columns with empty headers when using SmarterCSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smartercsv

I have a client who wants to maintain a broad span of flexibility when submitting CSV files to be uploaded. I've been using SmarterCSV to process the files, but have hit a snag where there are gaps in the columns of information--essentially the header line looks something like this:

`'header1',,,,,'header2','header3'`

SmarterCSV gives me this error:

`SmarterCSV::DuplicateHeaders (ERROR: duplicate headers: ,,,,,,,,,)`

Does anyone know of a way to have SmarterCSV just skip columns without headers and move on? I've tried something akin to the following with no luck:

```
options = {strip_whitespace: true, key_mapping: {nil => nil}
records = SmarterCSV.process("#{path}#{csv_file}", options)
```

**EDIT:**

I've also tried this, and it allows me to complete the processing, but results in an empty array:

```
options = {
      strip_whitespace: true, 
      key_mapping: {'' => nil},
      remove_unmapped_keys: true
    }
    records = SmarterCSV.process("#{path}#{csv_file}", options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make two changes:

1. set the `key_mapping:` to include all the keys you expect
2. remove `'' => nil` from the key mapping.
   eg

```
options = {
  strip_whitespace: true, # you can remove this since it's the default
  key_mapping: { column1: :column1, column2: :column2 },
  remove_unmapped_keys: true
}
```

Now unmapped keys, such as empty ones, will be removed.